# State changed from up to crashed in Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, heroku-cli

I am getting the following error on Heroku logs:

```
2018-10-29T00:48:34.198959+00:00 heroku[reminder.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-10-29T00:48:59.855673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=promo-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=253b5e26-384e-4b02-b65c-51342fb46a4e fwd="73.162.11.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-29T00:49:01.143244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=promo-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=b1b8cb23-01d8-4f59-ac42-a98f28cb9c10 fwd="73.162.11.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-29T00:56:23.879027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=promo-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=00c30077-8e31-4fea-a700-f7fffd45e446 fwd="73.162.11.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-29T00:56:25.162371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=promo-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=1684c085-7c4a-4f90-beed-a6667c60ab88 fwd="73.162.11.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

my Procfile is:

```
reminder: python src/quickstart.py
```

Heroku web page shows:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

Comment: replace `reminder: python src/quickstart.py` with `web: python src/quickstart.py` and make sure you have at least one web dyno running.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `web` process type on Heroku will allow you to receive HTTP requests.

You need to replace your Procfile:

```
reminder: python src/quickstart.py
```

Then, start a web dyno:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations

Comment: Did you redeploy after changing the Procfile?